# How to remove duplicate classes on click in Jquevery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two div (they are in the same place but have different z-index) and two css classes:

```
.gif_left {
z-index: 20;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 130px;
opacity: 1;
}
.gif_right {
z-index: 19;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 80px;
opacity: 0;
}
.click {
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
.click2 {
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

And Jquvery code for them:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.gif_left').click (function() {
$('.gif_left').toggleClass('click');
$('.gif_right').toggleClass('click2');
});

$('.gif_right').click (function () {
$('.gif_left').toggleClass('click2');
$('.gif_right').toggleClass('click');
}); 
});
```

Now when I click on `.gif_left` everything works correctly and its assigned class `.click`, and `.gif_right` is assigned class `.click2`.
But when I click on `.gif_right`, both divs become visible on the screen. Each div is assigned `.click` and `.click2` at the same time. When I click again `.gif_left` gets class `.click_2` and `.gif_right` gets `.click` again.

What do I need to change or add in the code so classes aren't duplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid duplicate classes you can explicitly remove classes that should not exist. Here is the updated version of your jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gif_left').click(function() {
        $('.gif_left').addClass('click').removeClass('click2');
        $('.gif_right').addClass('click2').removeClass('click');
    });

    $('.gif_right').click(function() {
        $('.gif_left').addClass('click2').removeClass('click');
        $('.gif_right').addClass('click').removeClass('click2');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the class that you need to hide when you click `.gif_right`. The `toggleClass()` function checks for the class in a set of elements. You can read it more about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...

    $('.gif_right').click (function () {
        $('.gif_left').toggleClass('click click2');
        $('.gif_right').toggleClass('click2 click');
    }); 
});
```